# Creating stub for `private static readonly` field

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

Due on [Improper Instantiation problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/antipatterns/improper-instantiation/) it is recommended to create `private static readonly` instance of `HttpClient`.

Due on lack of time I have injected [`mocked` client](https://github.com/richardszalay/mockhttp#usage) into test method with `client` as their parameter.

The problem is how can I in simple way inject `mock` into `private static readonly HttpClient` field of `SingleHttpClientInstanceController`?

Comment: You should use an IoC container and configure it to always pass a single instance.

Comment: Some code needed

Comment: Learn about IoC containers.  The exact details depend on how you structure your code.

Comment: Just get rid of the readonly.  There are many software anti-patterns that have to fall by the wayside to make it testable.

Comment: Your options are: 1) Use some abstraction rather than the field directly, or 2) Purchase an expensive solution such as Microsoft Fakes (VS Ultimate) or JustMock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can I in simple way inject `mock` into `private static readonly
>   HttpClient` field of `SingleHttpClientInstanceController`?

Answer: There is no simple way.

Suggestion:

Abstract the resource behind an accessor

```
public interface IHttpClientAccessor {
    HttpClient HttpClient { get; }
}
```

and inject that into the dependent controller.

```
public class SingleHttpClientInstanceController : ApiController {
    private readonly HttpClient HttpClient;

    public SingleHttpClientInstanceController(IHttpClientAccessor httpClientAccessor) {
        HttpClient = httpClientAccessor.HttpClient;
    }

    // This method uses the shared instance of HttpClient for every call to GetProductAsync.
    public async Task<Product> GetProductAsync(string id) {
        var hostName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
        var result = await HttpClient.GetStringAsync(string.Format("http://{0}:8080/api/...", hostName));
        return new Product { Name = result };
    }
}
```

The same should also be done for accessing `HttpContext` which is what was recently introduced in Asp.Net-Core's `IHttpContextAccessor`

An implementation of the `IHttpClientAcessor` can look something like this

```
public class HttpClientAccessor : IHttpClientAccessor {
    static readonly Lazy<HttpClient> client = new Lazy<HttpClient>(() => new HttpClient());
    public HttpClient HttpClient { get { return client.Value; } }
}
```

So now for tests you can inject mock of the dependency.

If using a DI container remember to register the accessor as a singleton as well.