# Unit Testing Class That Wraps HttpClient

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I am in the process of writing unit tests for a new project we've created and one of the issues I've come across is how to properly unit test something that effectively wraps HttpClient. In this case, I have written a RestfulService class that exposes basic methods for calling a REST service from C#.

Here is the simple interface that the class implements:

```
public interface IRestfulService
{
    Task<T> Get<T>(string url, IDictionary<string, string> parameters, IDictionary<string, string> headers = null);

    Task<T> Post<T>(string url, IDictionary<string, string> parameters, object bodyObject, IDictionary<string, string> headers = null);

    Task<string> Put(string url, IDictionary<string, string> parameters, object bodyObject, IDictionary<string, string> headers = null);

    Task<string> Delete(string url, object bodyObject, IDictionary<string, string> headers = null);

    Task<FileResponse?> Download(string url, IDictionary<string, string> urlParams = null, IDictionary<string, string> headers = null);
}
```

and here's is a trimmed down version of the implementation for example purposes:

```
public class RestfulService : IRestfulService
    {
        private HttpClient httpClient = null;
        private NetworkCredential credentials = null;
        /* boiler plate code for config and what have you */
        private string Host => "http://localhost";
        private NetworkCredential Credentials => new NetworkCredential("sampleUser", "samplePassword");
        private string AuthHeader
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.Credentials != null)
                {
                    return string.Format("Basic {0}", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(this.Credentials.UserName + ":" + this.Credentials.Password)));
                }
                else
                {
                    return string.Empty;
                }
            }
        }

        private HttpClient Client => this.httpClient = this.httpClient ?? new HttpClient();
        public async Task<T> Get<T>(string url, IDictionary<string, string> parameters, IDictionary<string, string> headers = null)
        {
            var result = await this.DoRequest(url, HttpMethod.Get, parameters, null, headers);
            if (typeof (T) == typeof (string))
            {
                return (T)(object)result;
            }
            else
            {
                return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(result);
            }
        }

        private async Task<string> DoRequest(string url, HttpMethod method, IDictionary<string, string> urlParams = null, object bodyObject = null, IDictionary<string, string> headers = null)
        {
            string fullRequestUrl = string.Empty;
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            if (headers == null)
            {
                headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            }

            if (this.Credentials != null)
            {
                headers.Add("Authorization", this.AuthHeader);
            }

            headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            fullRequestUrl = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", this.Host.ToString(), url, urlParams?.ToQueryString());
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, fullRequestUrl))
            {
                request.AddHeaders(headers);
                if (bodyObject != null)
                {
                    request.Content = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bodyObject), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                }

                response = await this.Client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var errDesc = response.ReasonPhrase;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
                {
                    errDesc += " - " + content;
                }

                throw new HttpRequestException(string.Format("RestfulService: Error sending request to web service URL {0}. Reason: {1}", fullRequestUrl, errDesc));
            }

            return content;
        }
    }
```

As you can see from the implementation it's a pretty thin wrapper that handles things like adding the auth headers (pulled from config) and some other small basic things.

My question: How can I mock the call to `Client.SendAsync` to return predetermined responses to verify deserialization is happening properly and that the auth headers are added? Would it make more sense to move the adding of the auth headers out of `DoRequest` and Mock the implementation of `DoRequest` before running my test?

Comment: [Mocking HttpClient is Hard.](https://gingter.org/2018/07/26/how-to-mock-httpclient-in-your-net-c-unit-tests/)  [See also](https://tech.findmypast.com/dont-mock-what-you-dont-own/).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for the link, I'm going to read up on that now.

Comment: This should be tested against actual services by using actual HttpClient.

Comment: @Fabio thanks for the reply, however, testing against the actual services that it is calling would be a regression test and beyond the scope of a unit test. I have found a way to accomplish what I need and will be posting an answer to this question shortly.

Comment: Have you considered using [Flurl](https://flurl.io/)? It's a thin wrapper above HttpClient. It has a great syntax, and is testable.

Comment: @mason I have not, however, I was able to hack together something that is testable and will allow me to continue. I Will look at this in the future though. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out using an accessor for the HttpClient and then mocking out the HttpMessageHandler. Here is the code I used.

```
public interface IHttpClientAccessor
    {
        HttpClient HttpClient
        {
            get;
        }
    }

    public class HttpClientAccessor : IHttpClientAccessor
    {
        public HttpClientAccessor()
        {
            this.HttpClient = new HttpClient();
        }

        public HttpClient HttpClient
        {
            get;
        }
    }

    public interface IRestfulService
    {
        Task<T> Get<T>(string url, IDictionary<string, string> parameters, IDictionary<string, string> headers = null);
        Task<T> Post<T>(string url, IDictionary<string, string> parameters, object bodyObject, IDictionary<string, string> headers = null);
        Task<string> Put(string url, IDictionary<string, string> parameters, object bodyObject, IDictionary<string, string> headers = null);
        Task<string> Delete(string url, object bodyObject, IDictionary<string, string> headers = null);
        Task<FileResponse? > Download(string url, IDictionary<string, string> urlParams = null, IDictionary<string, string> headers = null);
    }

    public class RestfulService : IRestfulService
    {
        private HttpClient httpClient = null;
        private NetworkCredential credentials = null;
        private IHttpClientAccessor httpClientAccessor;
        public RestfulService(IConfigurationService configurationService, IHttpClientAccessor httpClientAccessor)
        {
            this.ConfigurationService = configurationService;
            this.httpClientAccessor = httpClientAccessor;
        }

        public string AuthHeader
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.Credentials != null)
                {
                    return string.Format("Basic {0}", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(this.Credentials.UserName + ":" + this.Credentials.Password)));
                }
                else
                {
                    return string.Empty;
                }
            }
        }

        private IConfigurationService ConfigurationService
        {
            get;
        }

        private string Host => "http://locahost/";
        private NetworkCredential Credentials => this.credentials ?? new NetworkCredential("someUser", "somePassword");
        private HttpClient Client => this.httpClient = this.httpClient ?? this.httpClientAccessor.HttpClient;
        public async Task<T> Get<T>(string url, IDictionary<string, string> parameters, IDictionary<string, string> headers = null)
        {
            var result = await this.DoRequest(url, HttpMethod.Get, parameters, null, headers);
            if (typeof (T) == typeof (string))
            {
                return (T)(object)result;
            }
            else
            {
                return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(result);
            }
        }

        private async Task<string> DoRequest(string url, HttpMethod method, IDictionary<string, string> urlParams = null, object bodyObject = null, IDictionary<string, string> headers = null)
        {
            string fullRequestUrl = string.Empty;
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            if (headers == null)
            {
                headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            }

            if (this.Credentials != null)
            {
                headers.Add("Authorization", this.AuthHeader);
            }

            headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            fullRequestUrl = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", this.Host.ToString(), url, urlParams?.ToQueryString());
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, fullRequestUrl))
            {
                request.AddHeaders(headers);
                if (bodyObject != null)
                {
                    request.Content = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bodyObject), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                }

                response = await this.Client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var errDesc = response.ReasonPhrase;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
                {
                    errDesc += " - " + content;
                }

                throw new HttpRequestException(string.Format("RestfulService: Error sending request to web service URL {0}. Reason: {1}", fullRequestUrl, errDesc));
            }

            return content;
        }
    }
```

And here is the implementation for test cases:

```
private RestfulService SetupRestfulService(HttpResponseMessage returns, string userName = "notARealUser", string password = "notARealPassword")
    {
        var mockHttpAccessor = new Mock<IHttpClientAccessor>();
        var mockHttpHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        var testServiceEndpoints = Options.Create<Configuration.ServiceEndpoints>(new Configuration.ServiceEndpoints()
        {OneEndPoint = "http://localhost/test", AnotherEndPoint = "http://localhost/test"});
        var testAuth = Options.Create<AuthOptions>(new AuthOptions()
        {Password = password, Username = userName});
        mockHttpHandler.Protected().Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>()).ReturnsAsync(returns).Verifiable();
        mockHttpAccessor.SetupGet(p => p.HttpClient).Returns(new HttpClient(mockHttpHandler.Object));
        return new RestfulService(new ConfigurationService(testServiceEndpoints, testAuth), mockHttpAccessor.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TestAuthorizationHeader()
    {
        // notARealUser : notARealPassword
        var expected = "Basic bm90QVJlYWxVc2VyOm5vdEFSZWFsUGFzc3dvcmQ=";
        var service = this.SetupRestfulService(new HttpResponseMessage{StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK, Content = new StringContent("AuthorizationTest")});
        Assert.Equal(expected, service.AuthHeader);
    }

   [Fact]
   public async Task TestGetPlainString()
   {
        var service = this.SetupRestfulService(new HttpResponseMessage() { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK, Content = new StringContent("test") });
        var result = await service.Get<string>("test", null, null);
        Assert.Equal("test", result);
   }
```

This allows me to pass the desired response into `SetupRestfulService` along with credentials and get back an object I can call my functions on. It's a little less than Ideal but it saves me from having to flesh out the entire adapter pattern and going down that rabbit hole.

Comment: Similar to what I did here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45154289/5233410

Comment: @Nkosi wow, this is almost like bumping into a celebrity! I definitely read your posts on a couple of threads and armed with that info I hacked this together. I didn't get a chance in those threads to say it so I'll say it here, Thank You for your help.

Comment: Glad to help. Happy Coding.